# HttpClient 4.3 changed argument (query) handling?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I´m sure that I`m missing something but it seams to me that the behavior hows the HttpClient sends request differs, when it comes to arguments.

The Problem is, that any request with arguments results in the status code 501.
With the 4.2 version those requests was handled properly.

The tricky part is, that there is nothing spatial about the arguments and the problem also accuser when the arguments are build via URIBuilder as described here:
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html

I suppose i need a way to put the params:BasicHttpsParams collection and not concatenate them with the plain uri - since they seam not to get recognized that way by HttpGet. Did something changed between 4.2 and 4.3 at this point?

here is the code how our get Method is implemented:

```
private static CloseableHttpClient httpAgent = initializeCloseableHttpClient(connectionManager);

private static CloseableHttpClient initializeCloseableHttpClient(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager) {
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                               .setConnectTimeout(500)
                               .setConnectionRequestTimeout(DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
                               .setSocketTimeout(DEFAULT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT)
                               .build();

    ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom()
                               .setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                               .build();

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                               .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                               .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                               .setDefaultConnectionConfig(connectionConfig)
                               .build();
     return httpClient;
}

public static String get(String url, Map<String, String> arguments) {
    String argumentString = getArgumentString(arguments == null ? EMPTY_COLLECTION : arguments.entrySet());
    HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url + argumentString);
    return request(getMethod, null);
}

private static String request(HttpUriRequest method, AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails) {
    InputStreamProcessor processor = new CopyToStringInputStreamProcessor();
    processStream(method, authenticationDetails, processor);
    return (String) processor.getResult();
}

 private static void processStream(HttpUriRequest method, AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails, InputStreamProcessor processor) {
    try {
        HttpClientContext context = null;
        if (authenticationDetails != null) {

            CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(authenticationDetails.getUsername(), authenticationDetails.getPassword());
            credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(method.getURI().getHost(), method.getURI().getPort()), credentials);

            // Create AuthCache instance
            AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
            // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
            BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
            HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(method.getURI().getHost(), method.getURI().getPort(), method.getURI().getScheme());
            authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);

            // Add AuthCache to the execution context
            context = HttpClientContext.create();
            context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
            context.setAuthCache(authCache);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpAgent.execute(method, context);

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != 200 && statusCode != 302) { // redirect is also ok
                throw new HttpClientException(String.format("A http request responds with failure code: %d (%s), requested uri: %s", statusCode, response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase(), method.getRequestLine().getUri()));
            }

            try {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    try (InputStream responseStream = entity.getContent()) {
                        processor.process(responseStream);
                        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex) {
                        throw ex; // In case of an IOException the connection will be released back to the connection manager automatically
                    }
                    catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                        method.abort(); // In case of an unexpected exception you may want to abort the HTTP request in order to shut down the underlying connection and release it back to the connection manager.
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new HttpClientException(String.format("IO exception while processing http request on url: %s. Message: %s", method.getRequestLine().getUri(), e.getMessage()), e);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new HttpClientException(String.format("Exception while processing http request on on url: %s. Message: %s", method.getRequestLine().getUri(), e.getMessage()), e);
    }
}
```

Any advises what might be wrong are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Print your request and response headers, could be useful.

Comment: The header group is empty in both cases (before and after the migration)

Comment: The above is valid for the request. The response header looks as follows: HttpClient 2.5: [Date: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 13:08:40 GMT, Server: LocalTestServer/1.1, Content-Length: 8, Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8, Connection: Keep-Alive] HttpClient 3.3: [Date: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 13:12:43 GMT, Content-Length: 0, Connection: Close]

Answer (score 0):

5xx is a server error. There's no reason to assume that anything is wrong on the client until you look into your server logs. If you don't have access to server logs, check the response text, there might be an indication of what failed on the server in there.

Comment: I´ll do as you suppose, but the strange thing is that the same (test server) instance did her job with HttpClient 4.2

Comment: It's quite possible something did change in 4.3.x which is causing the server to fail. But the best way to find out what that is to start diagnosing from the server.

Comment: Wire logs of both sessions (4.2 and 4.3) might also help http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/logging.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but i`m already working with a debugger, so i can trace each and every step until the the request is executed and after the response arrived. The server might be more informative here - but as far is I see, it only says that there was no parameters.

Comment: "The main theme of the 4.3 release
series is streamlining of component configuration and deprecation of the old configuration API based on HttpParams in favor of constructor-based dependency injection and plain objects for configuration parameters." from https://www.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/httpcore/RELEASE_NOTES-4.3.x.txt. If you're sure the server is returning 501 for what's effectively a bad request (400), then compare logs to confirm the requests are different and update your client accordingly.

Comment: Thats what I did, i updated partly the LokalTestServer to get rid of HttpParams and use not deprecated methods only and now the tests with only one parameter are succeeding. However the tests containing multiple params still run into the same problem. In the real world the requests are running against a solr cluster, which is 4.6.1 so its quite fresh. The error there is 400 as you pointed out, i`m missing something with the param handling in HttpClient 4.3.

Comment: Also mentionable is that the request method from client to solr is POST not GET. Actually all POST method tests (with single or multiple parameters/arguments) are succeeding. But in real World there is a 400 and the parameters seams to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was laying in the following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {...}
```

I don´t know when it found its way into the code, and though it has its reason why the request ist sendet 3 times, but found out that it was not there before and after removing this, everything started to work fine.